# Write $f(x)$ as a product of two polynomials

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Consider the polynomial $f(x)=8x^3-50x^2+17x-30$. If $f(6)=0$ write $f(x)$ as a product of two polynomials

Comment: Do you know about the very close connection between the roots of a polynomial and its factors?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I factor the expressions and got x=6

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For equations, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With

$f(x) = 8x^3 - 50x^2 +17x - 30, \tag 1$

we factor $f(x)$ over $\Bbb R[x]$ *via* synthetic division as follows:

$x - 6$ into $8x^3$ is $8x^2$;

$8x^3 - 50x^2 +17x - 30 - 8x^2(x - 6)$
$= 8x^3 - 50x^2 +17x - 30 - 8x^3 + 48x^2 = -2x^2 + 17x - 30; \tag 2$

$x - 6$ into $-2x^2$ is $-2x$;

$-2x^2 + 17x - 30 - (-2x)(x - 6)$
$= -2x^2 + 17x - 30 + 2x^2 - 12x = 5x - 30; \tag 3$

$x - 6$ into $5x- 30$ is $5$;

we gather quotient terms, yielding

$8x^2 -2x + 5; \tag 4$

***We Check:***

$(x - 6)(8x^2 - 2x + 5) = 8x^3 - 2x^2 + 5x - 48x^2 + 12x - 30$
$= 8x^3 - 50x^2 + 17x - 30 = f(x); \tag 5$

thus,

$f(x) = 8x^3 - 50x^2 +17x - 30 = (x - 6)(8x^2 - 2x + 5). \tag 6$

the quadratic formula applied to $8x^2 - 2x + 5 = 0$ yields two further roots $r_\pm$:

$r_\pm = \dfrac{2 \pm \sqrt{4 - 160}}{16} = \dfrac{2 \pm \sqrt{-156}}{16}$
$\dfrac{2 \pm \sqrt{-4 \cdot 39}}{16} = \dfrac{1 \pm i\sqrt{39}}{8} \in \Bbb C \setminus \Bbb R; \tag 7$

since $r_\pm$ are non-real complex numbers, $8x^2 - 2x + 5$ is irreducible over $\Bbb R$, and $f(x)$ cannot be factored further in $\Bbb R[x]$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $f(6)=0$, you know that $(x-6)$ divides your polynomial. Use polynomial long division to divide this out and whatever you get as the answer will be the other factor.

Comment: Thank you so much